# Hovering over 1 div to change another divs content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

(I have tried tips from multiple posts on here but still no luck)

Essentially I  want to hover over div "b" and the content in div "a" to change.
In the actual code diva and dib have different parents so cant be done css only.

simplified html :

```js
$("#divb").hover(function() {
  $("#div a").css('content', 'url(img2.png)');
}, function() {
  $("#diva").css('content', 'url(img1.png)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="diva">A</div>

<div id="divb">B</div>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated :) Ive been trying different methods for hours

Answer (score 2):

You are doing great. You just need to remove the whitespace on `div a` to `diva` in order to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

In your html file:

```html
<div id="diva"></div>
<div id="divb"></div>
```

In your js file:

```
$('#divb').on('hover', () => {
    $("#div a").css('content','url(img2.png)');
    $("#diva").css('content','url(img1.png)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#divb")` will get element with `id="divb"` you should use `#` before `id` not tag name i.e `div`.Below is demo with example images

```js
$('div#a').hover(function(){
  $('div#b').css('content','url(https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg)');
},function(){
  $('div#b').css('content','url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/c2/9d/7d/c29d7d7388523342de339fdc2611e80f--flamingo-art-flamingo-beach.jpg?b=t)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
```